# gsutil rsync: amount transfered differs from `du`

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to backup a large directory (several terabytes) to google cloud, using the following command:

`gsutil -m rsync -r -e local_dir/ gs://target/bucket`

In summary, run in parallel (`-m`), recursively (`-r`) search the directory `local_dir/` (don't follow symlinks `-e`), and store it remotely in the bucket `gs://target/bucket`.

This operation completes succesfully:

```
[666.4k/666.4k files][ 6.3 TiB / 6.3 TiB] 100% Done
Operation completed over 666.4k objects/6.3 TiB.
```

One thing that worries me, however, is that the folder size is different when I run `du`:

```
$ du --max-depth 1 -h local_dir/
...
7.6T    local_dir
```

Can anyone explain where the discrepancy of more than 1 TiB comes from, compared to what `gsutil` transfered, and what `du` reports?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Part of the difference is that Linux du is reporting in units of terabytes (10^12 bytes), while gsutil cp is reporting in units of tebibytes (2^40). Thus, the Linux du units are 1.0995 times larger than the gsutil cp units. Additionally, directories and inodes consume space beyond the file data bytes. For example, if you run these commands:

```
mkdir tmp
cd tmp
for f in {1..1000};do
touch $f
done
du -h
```

it reports 24K used, even though each of the files is empty (so, an average of 2.4k bytes per inode). And if you remove the temp files and run du -s on the directory, it consumes 4k bytes. So, your 666.4k files would consume approx 16 MB plus however much for the number of directories that were contained. Also, the amount used may differ depending on the type of filesystem you're using. The numbers I reported above are for an ext4 filesystem running on Debian Linux.

Comment: Is du reporting in terabytes? I've been using `du -h`, not `du --si`, and I believe `du -h` reports also in Tebibytes, although it uses the wrong unit. Excerpt from the man page: `--si: like -h, but use powers of 1000 not 1024`

Comment: You're right, that's what the manpage says. But it doesn't seem to be correct. Example:
mkdir t; cp /usr/bim/vim t; cd t; du -h
(reports 3.1M)
ls -l
(reports 3173864)

And if you calculate 3173864/(1024*1024) the result is 3.0268, not 3.1 (and 3.03 is what gsutil ls -l reports)

Comment: Now that's interesting, thanks. Alright I think I trust `gsutil rsync`s results enough to remove the directory now.

Comment: One other thing you could do to give yourself more confidence that gsutil copied everything correctly would be to use gsutil to copy everything uploaded back down to another directory, and then diff -r the original and new directory.